# TypeScript: Object is possibly 'undefined'. after conditional creation on object with optional, well-defined keys

Tags: typescript, undefined

I have this code

```
type t = "a" | "b"
const o: { [key in t]?: Array<number> } = {}
interface Thing {
    t: t;
}
const things: Array<Thing> = [{ t: "a"}]
for (const thing of things ) {
    if (!(thing.t in o)) o[thing.t] = []
    o[thing.t].push(1)
}
```

And get the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMULxQEQENFQD5IEaIFAGMB7AOwGdZCAuKAbygG0BrCEKAS2JgF0B+agQQBOg5CAA8xAK4BbLBEEA+KAF94tZbg7B5AM2T5oAFQAWHAOa1cUazGrAA3Lg1EysYKeJnSA4aLEnzJQR6OmBqFERlLlwdQkEoAAoXchgPC0IdVPNSKABKSxt2TISAQgT3cwA6WA4oQlz8wnoKz2quNXpowqaWszbKsElSYwSARlynIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is to

```
for (const thing of things) {
    ; (o[thing.t] ??= []).push(1)
}
```

Comment: I forgot the word what way it is, if you can remond me please do

Comment: Excellent that works! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Comment: @dbrugger I mean it's not the "right" way or the "proper" way, but the way it's considered to be good or smth

Comment: I think it is actually. First I thought the notation is just a syntax shortcut, and thought it is a bug that it doesn't work in the longer expression.
The problem with the two steps is that it could change in the meantime if it runs in a server and the object is accessed elsewhere. Probably typescript has no way to understand the execution context.

Comment: @dbrugger JS is single-threaded, so no, it can't change (unleast it's a Proxy or has getters, but that's not true for `{}` you've just created)

Answer (score 0):

In const o: { [key in t]?: Array } = {}
You add ? so that make that param optional

somethink like this maybe can help

```
  type t = 'a' | 'b';

  const o: { [key in t]: Array<number> } = { a: [], b: [] };
  interface Thing {
    t: t;
  }
  const things: Array<Thing> = [{ t: 'a' }];
  for (const thing of things) {
    if (!(thing.t in o)) o[thing.t] = [];
    o[thing.t].push(1);
  }
```

Comment: Yes I want to keep the keys optional because in my real use case that list is a lot longer and I do not need a bunch of empty arrays in the object.